# Azure Data Factor -how to implement data consistency with copy task

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

What is the best practice to handle transaction consistency when implementing copy data task with azure data factory?

For example, after successful copy of data from source sql server database to sink sql server database the data needs to be marked in source as copied.

1. copy data from source to a staging table on sink
2. merge data from staging table to final destination table thru stored procedure
3. mark data in source as copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADF Copy activity click on Settings tab. Under settings tab you enable "`Data consistency verification`" & "`Enable logging`". The Data Consistency Verification is not only provide successfully copied data from source to destination also verifies the consistent between source and destination.
[image]

After Copy activity done Data Consistency Verification provides the entire verification result.

[image]

Please refer: [click here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/you-can-enable-data-consistency-verification-in-copy-activity/ba-p/1947297)

**Copy data from source to staging**
Use copy activity and configure source and sink tables as source and sink datasets in copy activity.

**Merge data from staging table to final destination table through stored procedure**
Use stored procedure activity to call your Stored procedure and perform required Operation.

**Mark data in source as copied**
You can use Stored Procedure, dataflow or Function to raise a flag in source after successful copy of data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can follow this documentation [Incrementally load data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-powershell).

1. Select the watermark column.
   Select one column for each table in the source data store, which you can identify the new or updated records for every run. Normally, the data in this selected column (for example, last_modify_time or ID) keeps increasing when rows are created or updated. The maximum value in this column is used as a watermark.
2. Prepare a data store to store the watermark value.In this tutorial, you store the watermark value in a SQL database.
3. Create a pipeline with the following activities:
   a. Create a ForEach activity that iterates through a list of source table names that is passed as a parameter to the pipeline. For each source table, it invokes the following activities to perform delta loading for that table.
   b. Create two lookup activities. Use the first Lookup activity to retrieve the last watermark value. Use the second Lookup activity to retrieve the new watermark value. These watermark values are passed to the Copy activity.
   c. Create a Copy activity that copies rows from the source data store with the value of the watermark column greater than the old watermark value and less than the new watermark value. Then, it copies the delta data from the source data store to Azure Blob storage as a new file.
   d. Create a StoredProcedure activity that updates the watermark value for the pipeline that runs next time.

Here is the high-level solution diagram:
[image]